# Accessing instance properties inside of an array

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript, instance, multidimensional-array

I've imported several images into an actionScript 3 document. I've turned them all into symbols (movie clips) and given them instance names to reference from ActionScript.

Ok, so I'm putting the instances into an array so I can loop through them easily, but for some reason, whenever I'm putting in the instance name, I do a trace on the value in the array and it's giving me the symbol object back, rather than the instance object.

Basically trying to loop through the array to make each instance's visibility = false

Here's a sample:

```
var large_cap_extrusion_data: Array = new Array();
large_cap_extrusion_data[0] = large_cap_extrusion_menu_button;
large_cap_extrusion_data[1] = extrusion_border_large_cap
large_cap_extrusion_data[2] = "Large Cap";
large_cap_extrusion_data[3] = large_cap_main_menu_button;

var extrusion_data: Array = new Array();
extrusion_data[0] = large_cap_extrusion_data;

trace(extrusion_data[0][0]);
```

The traces gives:

```
[object large_cap_menu_button]
```

(the parent symbol)

rather than:

"large_cap_extrusion_menu_button"

I'd be very grateful if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong...

Comment: Actually, never mind, it was a problem with another part of my script that was stopping visible being accessed. Non problem, all fixed now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

when you trace and object, by default it describes it type. What you want is the "name" property of the object. 
Try this:
trace(extrusion_data[0][0].name);
that should give you the instance nema of the large_cap_menu_button rather than the class description. Either way, you have the right object I bet.